# Groupby one column and top N from other columns pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a df:

```
main_id    b_code    Scores
  1          ABC      0.56
  1          ABC      0.21
  1          BCD      0.7
  1          QWE      0.3
  1          ZXC      0.8
  2          ABC      0.26
  2          ABC      0.81
  2          BCD      0.24
  2          QWE      0.87
  2          ZXC      0.43
```

I HAVE to find top 2 b_code for each main_id,depending upon their scores.

my final result should be:

```
main_id    b_code   Scores
1           ZXC      0.8
1           ABC      0.56
2           QWE      0.87
2           ABC      0.81
```

i tried to do with groupby and nlargest but results were wrong.

Comment: Congrat to 1k :)

Comment: @jezrael : Thanks! But for me you are a GOD :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['main_id','Scores'], ascending=[True,False]).groupby('main_id').head(2)
print (df)
   main_id b_code  Scores
4        1    ZXC    0.80
2        1    BCD    0.70
8        2    QWE    0.87
6        2    ABC    0.81
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of all columns without `main_id` and `Scores` + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('b_code').groupby('main_id')['Scores'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
print (df)
   main_id b_code  Scores
0        1    ZXC    0.80
1        1    BCD    0.70
2        2    QWE    0.87
3        2    ABC    0.81
```